# return response for module.export from promise chain function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a chain of function with premise which is working perfectly. However, I'm still don't understand how all this exactly work and the only way I can access data is like this :

```
getAxiosUrls()
   .then(getNbShares)
   .then(console.log)
```

When I'm trying to pass an argument instead of `console.log` got an error as `argument is not defined`. So how do I pass my `(console.log)` response in something like this :

```
const my_data = function(req, res) {
    //probably something else here
return res.send(response);
}
```

I'm working with express so at the end I need to do a `module.exports` :

```
module.exports = {
    my_data
};
```

Again I'm sorry if all this sound confuse. I'm still learning and still be very confuse by promise, callback and request method.

---

If needed here is my promised function :

First:

```
const getAxiosUrls = function() { 
    return axios.get("http://localhost:3000/gatable")
      .then(function (response) {
          return urls = response.data.rows.map( ([x, y, z]) => y )
    })
}
```

Second :

```
const getNbShares = function() {
    return Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)
        .map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
            const share = $('.nb-shares').html();
            let shareTuple = {};
                shareTuple[urls[index]] = share;
                return shareTuple;
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));
}
```

and then :

```
getAxiosUrls()
   .then(getNbShares)
   .then(console.log)
```

Comment: Please read up some basics about promises before posting more questions about this problem. There is an excellent article about promises in the documentation section of this site: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally with come up with this :

```
const shares = function(req, res) {
    return getAxiosUrls()
   .then(getNbShares)
   .then(function (response, error) {
    return res.send(response);;
});}
```